# Site.login(username,password,Starturl) returns null

Tags: force.com-sites

```
        String startURL = '/PageALanding';
        String retUrl = 
        System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('retURL');
        system.debug('+++++++++++++++++++++++'+returl);

        if(retUrl != null){
            return Site.login(username, password, retUrl);
        }


        PageReference pr = Site.login(username, password, startUrl);
        System.debug('sjhdfhsdf'+pr);

        if (pr == null){
            loginError = true;
        }

        return pr;
```

Comment: It does return null in a test or other non-Site context. Also make sure you have `apex:pageMessages` in your page because the call adds error messages. In general, add more context to your question.

Comment: The error message displayed on the page :
ERROR 
Your login attempt has failed. Make sure the username and password are correct.

Comment: Have you created the right kind of User according to how your Site is configured? Reset the password if you have lost that.